# How to sign my app as "Identified Apple developer"?

Tags: macos, security, executable-jar, sign

OSX won't run my app due to "App is from unidentified developer". On Ubuntu and Win 8 it runs with no problems. It's a runnable jar created with Eclipse. How can I prepare the jar so that it can run normally with OSX? I can't relax the security setting becuase I am not admin of the target platform.

Comment: Relax the security settings.

Comment: @trojanfoe But I can't since I'm not the admin of the target system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Apple Identified Developer

To sign your application as an `Apple-Identified Developer` you will have to enroll yourself or company in the [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mac/). Once enrolled you will be granted several [different types of certificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW41) which can be used to codesign applications you distribute, whether within the Mac AppStore or outside of it.

### Unidentified Developer

If you'd rather not join the Apple Developer Program then you would need to inform users of your application to allow it to run through the [Gatekeeper settings](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18656?locale=en_US) from their System Preferences Security Panel, or to [override](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18658?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) the security as they launch the application (only required once).

Comment: links are dead :(

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă Try these: https://web.archive.org/web/20150926060624/https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18656?locale=en_US and https://web.archive.org/web/20141115061725/http://support.apple.com:80/kb/PH18658